# If a thrown error isn't "instanceof Error" then Jest doesn't show the failing line number

Tags: testing, jestjs

suppose i use this code from jest-puppeteer.

```
await page.waitForFunction('false', { timeout: 10 });
```

this fails, but doesn't give me the line number.

```
 FAIL  mytest.test.ts (5.03 s)
  My Described Thing
    ✕ User can do a thing (32 ms)

  ● My Described Thing › User can do a thing

    TimeoutError: Waiting failed: 10ms exceeded

      at Timeout.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/common/WaitTask.ts:91:11)
```

if a catch the error, then `e instanceof Error` reports `false`,
which makes me suspect [this line number in jest](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/blob/49bacb9620b87c476bd5ba1b30e26ca2c4f42a70/packages/jest-snapshot/src/printSnapshot.ts#L181).

the stacktrace looks like so:

```
TimeoutError: Waiting failed: 10ms exceeded
        at Timeout.<anonymous> (...node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/common/WaitTask.ts:91:11)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
```

which comes from [here in puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/packages/puppeteer-core/src/common/WaitTask.ts#L92C22-L92C22). but if i throw that same error manually, everything works as expected.

the only difference i see is that in the failing case, `e instanceof Error` returns false, whereas if i create it manually, it's true. i don't know why this happens but either way, it seems like a bug that jest discriminates on the type of the error. if you caught an error, just treat it like an error for reporting failure line numbers, right?